# How to get current working directory before changing it

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have this function

```
snip-git(){
    cd  ${snippetdir}
    git add .
    git commit -m "."
    git push -u
}
```

When git finishes pushing the changes, I want to get back to the directory I was when I called `snip-git`.

I tried this

```
snip-git(){
    cwd=$(pwd)
    cd  ${snippetdir}
    ...
    cd cwd
}
```

But it ends up reading the ned directory rather than the old one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is making your works in a subshell only:

```
snip-git() (
    cd  -- "$snippetdir"
    git add .
    git commit -m "."
    git push -u
)
```

---

There're some thing you want to fix in your function:

- Remember to always [quote your variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/38906).
- You refer variable using `$cwd` instead of `cwd`.

Comment: That's not working! I'm on root directory (but I could be anywhere), I run `snip-git' at the end of push, I'm not redirected to the root

Comment: @relidon: Did you change the `snip-git` definition to use `(...)` instead of `{ ... }`?

Comment: Now I did :) and it works. What's the difference in `( )` and `{ }`.  Thanks @cuonglm

Comment: @relidon: As I said in my answer, `( )` ran your commands in subshell, after your command done, the environment was restored.